# выборочное обновление записей MySQL - если значение целевого поля равно NULL, 0 или пустое

Tags: mysql

Необходимо выбрать записи по условию (например, диапазон id) из исходной table1 и обновить (вставить в) записи table2 с аналогичными id - только в те поля, которые равны  NULL, 0 или пустые. Как это сделать, не указывая имя каждого поля отдельно (полей очень много)?

Comment: *только в те поля, которые равны NULL, 0 или пустые.* Пустые - это строка нулевой длины, что ли? ну можно... *не указывая имя каждого поля отдельно* Ну можно, в виде хранимой процедуры с использованием динамического SQL... да только овчинка выделки не стОит, проще и быстрее не полениться и написать для каждого поля отдельно. Это как раз можно сделать и программно.

Comment: *и вставить в записи table2 с аналогичными id - только в те поля, которые* Вставить - это создать новую запись (а у неё всё будет "пустое"). То, что Вы имеете в виду, называется "обновить".

Comment: @Akina, спасибо за экспертную оценку и уточнение терминологии - тоже полезно. а пример такого "динамического SQL" - сильно сложная штука?

Comment: Нет, несложно, но аккуратности требует. Составьте такой запрос для 2-3 полей, а потом седлайте запрос в INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS и аккуратненько собирайте текст запроса с помощью GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT()).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использование построения текста запроса и выполнение динамического SQL.

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=01a8d0a3f037bcb6e4a3ed3d7b5c336d)**</kbd>

Comment: спасибо. не знаете как долго на dbfiddle.uk будет храниться этот фидл?

Comment: @SimplyOne Ну пока о пропавших фидлах я не слышал...

Answer (score 1):

Потенциально как-то так

```
 UPDATE t1
 INNER JOIN t2 ON (
        t1.id = t2.id
        AND t2.id between 100 and 200
     )
 SET t1.field = t2.field
 WHERE t1.field IS NULL
       OR t1.field = 0 
       OR t1.field = ''
```

Comment: я правильно понял, что field - это маска имени всех проверяемых полей?  и, соответственно, придется указывать это условие для всех полей. если да, то я уточнил свой вопрос - т.к. полей слишком много, а операция проверки выглядит универсальной